# Transistor Electric field

Tags: transistors, bjt, electric-field

For an unbiased transistor, is the maximum electric field larger in the emitter – base junction or in the base – collector junction? Why?

Comment: Welcome :-) For homework (or at least homework-sounding) questions like this, you need to show your own effort and research first (click the "edit" link below your question, add your research and analysis into the question, and make it clear exactly where you are stuck) . Also, don't be surprised if you get hints and socratic questions, leading you to your own discoveries, rather than someone handing you the answer. Failure to show your own work, research and analysis might lead to the question being quickly closed. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is homework with no own effort to solve.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt the question backward. Sketch the band diagram, and the electric field part should become aparent. You will have to make some assumptions about typical dopant concentration in the various regions.